# Multiple For-Loops

Tags: c#, for-loop

**EDIT:** I have updated my question and I know that I can increase the loop instead of 4 to 12 but the reason I have separate three for-loop is due to that; after iterating first loop i have to click carousel in order to go to the next next iteration as you can see my updated code. - sorry somehow i missed the code while copy/pasting.

I want to iterate through the rows, the total rows I have is 3 and every row has 4 columns, for an example:

```
row 1 has 4 columns
row 2 has 4 columns
row 3 has 4 columns
```

I have created 3 separate for-loop and my code works but I believe there is room to improve my code, can it have in one loop instead of three?

here is the code:

```
//first row

for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
{  
   string _image = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]/img", j, "1");                 
   string _text = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]", j, "2");
   ...........
   WaitForElement(By.XPath(_text)).Click();
}

_carouselDot = String.Format("id('HomePage1_Carousel1')/div/ul/li[{0}]/a", 2);
WaitForElement(By.XPath(_carouselDot)).Click();

//second row
for (int j = 4; j < 8; j++) 
{  
   string _image = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]/img", j, "1");                 
   string _text = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]", j, "2");
   ...........
   WaitForElement(By.XPath(_text)).Click();
}

_carouselDot = String.Format("id('HomePage1_Carousel1')/div/ul/li[{0}]/a", 3);
WaitForElement(By.XPath(_carouselDot)).Click();

//third row
for (int j = 8; j < 12; j++) 
{  
   string _image = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]/img", j, "1");                 
   string _text = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]", j, "2");
   ...........
   WaitForElement(By.XPath(_text)).Click();
}
```

Comment: If you're able to use the `Task Parallel Library` you would be able to run these in parallel. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: Yes there is a way to do it with 1 loop, most would suggest 2 loops, one nested in the other, but if you know that you **only** have 3 rows, than your code is fine

Comment: i have updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with this -

```
for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) 
{  
   string _image = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]/img", j, "1");                 
   string _text = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]", j, "2");
   ...........
   WaitForElement(By.XPath(_text)).Click();

   if(i % 4 == 3 && i != 11)
   {
      _carouselDot = String.Format("id('HomePage1_Carousel1')/div/ul/li[{0}]/a",
                                                                 (i/4 + 2));
       WaitForElement(By.XPath(_carouselDot)).Click();
   }
}
```

Comment: nope, it iterates firs time and second time the if condition is true and i think `i % 4 == 0 && i/4 <2` should be true only if the `i=4` whic is not the case with the above code

Comment: Updated as per your question - `i % 4 == 3` will be valid for values `3,7,11` and you want to execute it twice after `3` and `7` so check for `i != 11`.

Comment: `%` is a modulus operator which gets you `remainder` of division operation. So, it return true thrice for your loop for `3,7,11` and you want code to execute code after `3` and `7` but not after `11` hence check `i!=11`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can have a single loop that runs from 0 to 12...

```
for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) 
{  
   string _image = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]/img", j, "1");                 
   string _text = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]", j, "2");
   ...........
   WaitForElement(By.XPath(_text)).Click();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{  
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
   { 
        code here
   }
}
```

EDIT:

Because you edited your question, this seems better now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
       { 
            string _image = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]/img", j, "1");                 
            string _text = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]", j, "2");
            ...........
            WaitForElement(By.XPath(_text)).Click();

            if (i % 4 == 0)
            {
                _carouselDot = String.Format("id('HomePage1_Carousel1')/div/ul/li[{0}]/a", 2);
                WaitForElement(By.XPath(_carouselDot)).Click();
            }
       }
```

Comment: my upvote is suspended, waiting to see some comment involving `4*i+j`

Comment: Is it not that it should only execute if condition only if the `i == 4? i think so but its not happening and it runs first time and second time it `j % 4 == 0` = true

Comment: 0 % 4 = 0. Also, the % is one of the slowest operators you can find, though this will probably not matter much in this code.

Comment: I used 'j' instead of 'i' in the if, I fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

I see no difference between the three blocks other than the boundaries for j; so why can you not just do one loop?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this neatly and efficiently with two nested `for` blocks:

```
int rows = 3;
int cols = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
{  
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    { 
        int n = (cols * i) + j;
        string _image = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]/img", n, "1");                
        string _text = String.Format("id('gen{0}')/a[{1}]", n, "2");
        ...........
        WaitForElement(By.XPath(_text)).Click();
    }
    if (i < rows - 1) 
    {
        _carouselDot = String.Format("id('HomePage1_Carousel1')/div/ul/li[{0}]/a", 2);
        WaitForElement(By.XPath(_carouselDot)).Click();
    }
}
```

That way it is clear that you are dealing with three separated lines, and you can do especial processing at the end or start of each line as necessary, with simpler `if` clauses.

Edited for the new question, showing that you can do a `if()` after the inner `for` block.

Also, it is good practice to avoid magic numbers inside your code. With this you avoid bugs, and if you ever need to change the number of rows or columns, for example, you just have to change one variable.

Comment: what is the purpose of the `if(j %4)`?

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong. I thought that it was something that was done only at the end of each line...